# SSRS Mobile Reporting Not Supported

Tags: sql-server, azure, mobile, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I am trying to test out the new SSRS 2016 features, here's what I have so far:

- Signed up for an Azure trial
- Installed a SQL Server 2016 VM
- Created a DB
- Configured the reporting services to run classic reports
- Downloaded the Mobile Report Publisher

I have been trying stuff out using the predetermined data, however I wanted to pull in some data I'm familiar with. When I try to connect to the server (localhost/reports) I get a Server Error as the 'Server does not support mobile reports'.

Is there something I need to configure to enable this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

I think you are connecting to a **standard** edition of SQL SERVER 2016.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/overview.aspx

[image]
Unfortunately Mobile Reports are only supported in Enterprise Edition of SQL Server :(

Answer (score 0):

I took the same install steps as you (robbiecutting).  I'm running SS 2016 Developer edition.  I found that there was no option for creating Mobile reports in the Report Builder (desktop app), but there is one in the web-based reporting services portal:

Desktop app:
[image: Report Builder (desktop app)]

Web portal:
[image: Reporting Services Web portal]

It brings up a nice UI for creating one:

[image]