# How to view SSRS 2016 mobile reports on hand held devices

Tags: mobile, reporting-services

Can anyone explain different options to view ssrs 2016 mobile reports on hand held devices?

One way is to use Power BI mobile app but I am interested to know other options.

Comment: Possible help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311416/ssrs-mobile-reporting-not-supported?rq=1

Comment: I am using developer edition to test different features of SSRS 2016, later on I will use enterprise edition.